# Kendo File Upload control get grid row ID in edit pop up

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo Grid and editing is done via a pop up window.

In the pop up window I have a Kendo File Upload control. I want to send the grid row ID (or the unique identifier of the row) to upload file action in my ASP.NET MVC controller. This is the code in my edit pop up:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html
        .Kendo()
        .Upload()
        .Name("PdfModifiedDate")
        .Multiple(false)
        .Async(a => a
                .Save("UploadFile","Home")
        )
        .Events(events => events
            .Upload("OnImageUpload")
        )
    )
</div>
```

As you can see I have to use the event "OnImageUpload" to pass my ID. As you can see in the code below I have tried to access the property I need but I get "undefined".

```
function OnImageUpload(e) {
    console.log(e.container);

    var uid = $(e);
    //var publication = $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);
    //var id = publication.DocumentUpdateId;

    console.log(uid);
    //console.log(publication);
    //console.log(id);
    //e.data = { docUpdateId: id };
}
```

I can see via "Inspect element" that the ID I need is hidden but I can't access it.

Is there a way I can access the Grid row ID in the File Upload event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the edit dialog with Chrome Dev tools, I was able to get a a reference to the edit dialog. This isn't the ideal way of doing things but it worked for me.

```
function OnImageUpload(e) {

   var id = $("#grid").getKendoGrid()._editContainer.find("#DocumentUpdateId").val();

   e.data = { docUpdateId: id };

   console.log(e);
}
```